# Variable value is not increment after sliding

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment, slide

I have build a slide.
I have a ViewPage Activity that call a fragment every time that i swip to left or to right.
My question is:
      I have a variable int that in the initial state have the value 6 (week_of_year). When i slide to right is call a new fragment and the variable is not increment as i intend. The variable is only increment in the the second slide.
For example: 6 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8  instead of 6 -> 7 -> 8 ->  And i don't have ideia why this happens.

Here is my code:
         **ViewPage Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
/**
 * Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter
 */
    date = Calendar.getInstance();
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            if(itemOld < arg0){//right
                auxFront = auxFront + 1;
                oldStartWeek = oldStartWeek + auxFront; 
                auxFront=0;
            }
            else if(itemOld > arg0){//left
                auxBack = auxBack - 1;
                oldStartWeek = oldStartWeek + auxBack; 
                auxBack=0;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {    
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(mPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else{
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
    }
} 


/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in sequence
 */

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public ScreenSlidePageFragment getItem(int position) {
        /**
         * Pass values from ViewPage activity to Fragment
         */
        ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if(position == 0){
            oldStartWeek = date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            args.putInt("START_WEEK", oldStartWeek);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;

        }
        else if(position != 0){
            args.putInt("START_WEEK", oldStartWeek);
            f.setArguments(args);
            itemOld = mPager.getCurrentItem();
            return f;
        }
        return f;
} 

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  NUM_PAGES;
     }
  }

    }
```

**Fragment that is call in each slide**--------------------------------------------

```
        public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
               public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "week....." +getArguments().getInt("START_WEEK"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //show the correct value

headerWeek.setText(" Week Number:    "+getArguments().getInt("START_WEEK",0));  //But is not change corretly in the text view  ?????
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why this happens in your ViewPager, you can Log the onCreate, onPause, onResume, etc methods for each fragment. What happens is that the first two fragments are actually created about the same time. So the second fragment is created before it actually displays in a ViewPager, so by the time the user scrolls to the second fragment, there is often old data there.

My solution to this is a little hacky. Note that instead of displayDialog() you would do whatever you needed to update the view when the user is present.

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    fragmentActive = true;
    if (userVisible()){
        displayDialog();
    }
    else{
        recursiveWait();
    }
}

private void recursiveWait(){
    new WaitAndDoXTask(1000, new DoXListener() {

        @Override
        public void doX() {
            Log.d(TAG, "doX");
            if (userVisible()){
                displayDialog();
            }
            else if (fragmentActive){
                recursiveWait();
            }
        }
    }).execute();   
}

private boolean userVisible(){
    boolean vis = getUserVisibleHint();
    Log.d(TAG, "user visible = " + vis);
    return vis;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    fragmentActive = false;
}
```

Here is the WaitAndDoXTask:

```
public class WaitAndDoXTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

DoXListener mListener;
private int mTimeToWait;

/** This class will wait for the set time then do what is put into the listener.
 * 
 * 
 * Run like this:
 * new WaitAndDoXTask(1000, new DoXListener() {
 *  
 *  @Override
 *  public void doX() {
 *      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 *      
 *  }
 * }).execute();
 **/
public WaitAndDoXTask(int timeToWait, DoXListener listener){
    super();
    mTimeToWait = timeToWait;
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface DoXListener{
    public void doX();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(mTimeToWait);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if (mListener!=null){
        mListener.doX();
    }
}
```

}

Alternatively, if you could set up your Fragment with some Adapter and get notified via onDataSetChanged that might work better.